# Linux "locate" option not finding things

Tags: linux

I am looking at a file in my current directory (I'm root) called `jungledisk....`.  When I do a `locate *jungle*.*` or `*jungle*` it produces no results.... what am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure the locate database is getting updated in a timely fashion?  Maybe it's configured to update weekly and the files simply aren't in the database yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make sure you run

```
updatedb
```

first

Comment: When that doesn't fix the problem, what else to try?

Answer (score 0):

`locate` searches a database constructed by `updatedb`. you may need to rerun this command (or better yet, automate its running)

Answer (score 0):

`locate` depends on a list filename database which is updated by the `updatedb` command. The database only reflects the filesystem at the time `updatedb` was run, so new files won't be found, and removed files will be.

You might want to add it to root's crontab. The entry below will run it at midnight, every night:

```
[root@localhost]$ crontab -e
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/updatedb
```

Comment: Depending upon the distribution, this command might also get it to run automatically, once per day: `ln -s /usr/bin/updatedb /etc/cron.daily/updatedb` although most distributions would automatically put an entry in there.